# performance issue : storing a reference to DOM element vs using selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

So in my app, the user can create some content inside certain div tags, and each content, or as I call them "elements" has its own object. Currently I use a function to calculate the original div tag that the element has been placed inside using jquery selectors, but I was wondering in terms of performance, wouldn't it be better to just store a reference to the div tag once the element has been created, instead of calculating it later ?
so right now I use something like this :

```
$('.div[value='+divID+']')
```

but instead I can just store the reference inside the element, when im creating the element. Would that be better for performance ?

Comment: Yes, a local variable or property lookup will be much, much faster than creating a jQuery object, and doing DOM selection.

Comment: ...It's a little confusing since you seem to be using the word "element" to means something in your application, and the word "tag" to refer to a DOM element. So I'm not entirely following you.

Comment: @amnotiam yeah I understand what you mean ... the div "tag" looks like this : <div value="divID"> //elements are inserted here </div>
and then the elements can be a simpple div, a span or even a textbox

Comment: @hakim-sina I can't believe I didn't notice before but are you sure meant `'.div'`? That means everything with class="div". Attribute selectors can be pretty slow, so it would be much faster to narrow down to a container with an ID before using that. Example: `$('#ValueDivContainer div[value='+divID+']')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have lots of these bindings it would be a good idea to store references to them. As mentioned in the comments, variable lookups are much much faster than looking things up in the DOM - especially with your current approach. jQuery selectors are slower than the pure DOM alternatives, and that particular selector will be very slow.

Here is a test based on the one by epascarello showing the difference between jQuery, DOM2 methods, and references: http://jsperf.com/test-reference-vs-lookup/2. The variable assignment is super fast as expected. Also, the DOM methods beat jQuery by an equally large margin. Note, that this is with Yahoo's home page as an example.

Another consideration is the size and complexity of the DOM. As this increases, the reference caching method becomes more favourable still.

Answer (score 2):

A local variable will be super fast compared to looking it up each time. [Test to prove it](http://jsperf.com/test-reference-vs-lookup).

Comment: Does the call to `.html()` serve any purpose in the test? I would remove it since generally you want a reference to the element itself so you can do more things with it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a function that builds and returns an object. That part isn't super expensive but actual DOM lookups do involve a fair bit of work. Overhead isn't that high for a simple query that matches an existing DOM method like getElementById or getElementsByClassName (doesn't in exist in IE8 so it's really slow there) but yes the difference is between work (building an object that wraps a DOM access method) and almost no work (referencing an existing object). Always cache your selector results if you plan on reusing them.

Also, the xpath stuff that you're using can be really expensive in some browsers so yes, I would definitely cache that.

Stuff to watch out for:

- Long series of JQ params without IDs
- Selector with only a class in IE8 or less (add the tag name e.g. 'div.someClass') for a drastic improvement - IE8 and below has to hit every piece of HTML at the interpreter level rather than using a speedy native method when you only use the class
- xpath-style queries (a lot of newer browsers probably handle these okay)

When writing selectors consider how much markup has to be looked at to get to it. If you know you only want divs of a certain class inside a certain ID, do one of these $('#theID div.someClass') rather than just $('div.someClass');

But regardless, just on the principle of work avoidance, cache the value if you're going to use it twice or more. And avoid haranguing the DOM with repeated requests as much as you can.

Comment: jQuery isn't really anything noticeable here. It is DOM lookups that slow everything down.

Comment: Doing the DOM lookup is a part of the process of building that object but yes, that is the expensive part. Edited my post for more detail in that regard.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I would normally agree but if you look at my tests it does seem that with this particular selector, jQuery is much much slower - especially if you add more elements to the DOM.

Comment: @Radu It's an XPath selector. I'm not even sure browsers that support XPath could do anything with it using native code if the doctype and attributes weren't forcing the doc to be read as XML. That would mean JQuery would have to run through every single div element and check for a value attribute with that value.

Answer (score 0):

looking up an element by ID is super fast. i am not 100% sure i understand your other approach, but i doubt it would be any better than a simple lookup of an element by its id, browsers know how to this task best. from what you've explained I can't see how your approach would be any faster.

Comment: I would agree, if he was actually selecting the element by its Id.

Comment: He isn't looking it up by ID according to the code he posted.

Comment: @Radu, so the question is answered. What he's doing is lookup by class and attribute value... ugh, definitely not faster than lookup by id.

Comment: the problem is that I actually use a jquery selector, and not a simple div ID look up ... so divID in my example is a random id, which is stored on the div as a "value" attribute ... so each div looks like this : <div value="divID"> //elements are inserted here </div>